# overloading operator<< vs. namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading

I have a problem with overloading operator<< combined with namespaces. I have read the related posts, but still do not understand what is going on in my case..

The following code compiles OK:

file test_matrix.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_MATRIX_HPP
#define TEST_MATRIX_HPP

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_expression.hpp>
namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas; // shortcut name

namespace VecMat {
    typedef ublas::matrix<double> MatrixD; // matrix of doubles

    template<class MT>
    std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os,
                               const ublas::matrix_expression<MT> & M)
    {
        // Note: the matrix_expression<MT> has only one method "()", which
        // returns "& MT" or "const & MT" - a ref. to the included matrix object.
        typename MT::const_iterator1 it1;
        typename MT::const_iterator2 it2;
        for (it1 = M().begin1(); it1 != M().end1(); ++it1) {
            for (it2 = it1.begin(); it2 != it1.end(); ++it2) {
                os << *it2 << "\t";
            }
        os << std::endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
}; // namespace VecMat
#endif
```

file test_oper.cpp:

```
#include "test_matrix.hpp"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using VecMat::MatrixD;
using VecMat::operator<<;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// would be in a header file
void test1 ();
namespace Main {
    void test2 ();
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void test1 ()
{
    MatrixD X(10,3);
    VecMat::operator<<(cout << endl, X) << endl;
    cout << "X =" << endl << X << endl;
}

void Main::test2 ()
{
    MatrixD X(10,3);
    VecMat::operator<<(cout << endl, X) << endl;
    cout << "X =" << endl << X << endl;
}
```

Note that the *using VecMat::operator<<;* line is needed - without it, I get an error on the last line of *test1()* (using gcc 4.5):

> test_oper.cpp||In function 'void test1()':|
>   test_oper.cpp|22|error: no match for 'operator<<' in '((std::basic_ostream*)std::operator<<

Should not the compiler find the operator self using ADL, since the argument is of type *VecMat::MatrixD*?

My main problem, however, starts when I add a new class with its own operator<< to the *Main* namespace:

file test_other.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_OTHER_HPP
#define TEST_OTHER_HPP
#include <ostream>

namespace Main {
    class Foo {
        int n;
    };
    std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os, Foo const & foo);
}
#endif
```

If I then '#include "test_other.hpp"' from either of the two original files, the .cpp file won't compile, with the same error as above, only in the last line of *test2()*

> test_oper.cpp||In function 'void Main::test2()':|
>   test_oper.cpp|29|error: no match for 'operator<<' in '((std::basic_ostream*)std::operator<<

If I put *Foo* into a different namespace (either *VecMat* or a new one), it compiles OK. Does it mean that the compiler looks first into *Main*, finds one operator<< there (for Foo), and therefore stop searching and complains that it has found the wrong operator? Again, I would have thought that it would look into *VecMat* first, since the argument is of type *VecMat::MatrixD*?

I would appreciate both an explanation of what is going on and a recommendation how to resolve it in a cleanest possible way.

Thanks a lot.
Michal

**PS**: I posted the question also elsewhere and there it was suggested (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/47766/#msg259246) to add the *using VecMat::operator<<;* line also inside the *Main* namespace. This solves it - but I would still like to know why do I need those lines and whether this is the best/recommended solution.

Answer (score 3):

typedef doesn't introduce a new type. So `VecMat::MatrixD` is not a new type, it's an alias to `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>`, therefore the associated namespaces used in ADL are those of `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>`.