# Unable to resolve << across namespaces when used in operator<<(...)

Tags: c++, namespaces, ostream

I wrote an ostream operator for a class (in a namespace) which contains objects that have ostream operators defined in a different namespace.

A compilation error occurs when attempting to use `<<` in the `operator<<(...)` function, however when I rename the function to `print(...)` there is no compilation error. Everything is the same except the name of the function.

I have created a simplified example which demonstrates the problem and have tested it with Visual Studio 2012, gcc 4.1.2, and clang 3.3. The code is below. Change the `#define USEOSTREAM 1` to `#define USEOSTREAM 0` to change between using the `operator<<(...)` and `print(...)`

My understanding is that this construct should work. I am reluctant to blame the compiler, and even more reluctant to blame the language. Does anyone have an idea as to what is happening?

CodePad with `#define USEOSTREAM 1` http://codepad.org/b3cm038x
CodePad with `#define USEOSTREAM 0` http://codepad.org/0c11PkxL

```
#define USEOSTREAM 1

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Common {
    struct Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int val=0) : mVal(val) {}
        int mVal;
    };
}

namespace Utility {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Common::Foo& obj) {
        out << obj.mVal;
        return out;
    }
}

using namespace Utility;
namespace UnitTest {

    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar(int val=0) : foo(val) {}
        Common::Foo foo;
    };

    #if USEOSTREAM

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bar& bar) {
        out << bar.foo;                               //  Compile Error : no operator found of type 'const Common::Foo'
        // Utility::operator<<(out,vec[i]) << " " ;   //  No compile error for fully qualified name
        return out;
    }

    void printBar(const Bar& b) {
        std::cout << b;
    }

    #else

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out, const Bar& bar) {
        out << bar.foo;                                // No Compile Error
        return out;
    }

    void printBar(const Bar& b) {
        print(std::cout,b);
    }

    #endif

    void test01() {
        printBar(Bar(123));
    }
}

int main (int,char**) {
    UnitTest::test01();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(In writing the original SO question I found the solution, however I DO NOT understand WHY adding the using statement is required)*

It seems that `UnitTest::operator<<` is shadowing `Utility::operator<<`. The solution is to add a `using` statement before the operator function definition.

```
    using Utility::operator<<;  // New Line
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bar& bar) {
        out << bar.foo;
        return out;
    }
```

This issue is related to the following SO post
[overloading operator<< vs. namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895993/overloading-operator-vs-namespaces) and cplusplus.com forum post http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/47766/#msg259246

Comment: It's better to place `using Utility::operator<<` inside the output `operator<<` scope/body.

Comment: @40two: Fair point about scope  - do you understand why it is needed in the first place? It still does not make sense to me how `Utility::operator<<` is masked by `UnitTest::operator<<` since the functions have different parameters.

Comment: An alternative would be to move the `using namespace Utility;` line into `namespace UnitTest` rather than having it at the global scope.  The problem being that `UnitTest::operator<<` is shadowing ALL global scope `operater<<` functions.