# Compiler fails to find overload

Tags: c++, linux, namespaces, c++14

I was recently working with some simple types for some code I have and overloading the insertion operator for them so they could be easily printable.  I ran into a case where I literally got a thousand lines of compiler puke.  A simplified version is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

namespace ns{
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
using KeyValue = std::pair<KEY, VALUE>;

template<typename K, typename V>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const KeyValue<K,V>& arg){
  os << "Key: " << arg.first << " Value: " << arg.second;
  return os;
}
}


struct Foo_t{
  double a = 0;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Foo_t& f){
  os << "a: " << f.a;
  return os;
}



int main()
{
  Foo_t foo{6.283185};
  ns::KeyValue<std::string, Foo_t> foo_kv{"Foo_t", foo};

  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << foo_kv;

  std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

It turns out that the error is because `Foo_t` and its `operator<<` aren't in namespace `ns`.  If I add them to namespace `ns` and make the adjustments in main then it compiles fine. From my admittedly limited knowledge, I would've thought it would've been found via ADL, but that appears to not be the case. Why? Is there a better way to fix it other than just adding `Foo_t` to namespace `ns`?

Incidentally, the thousand lines of compiler puke was GCC trying to be helpful and listing all of the candidate overloads of `operator<<` it knew of.

Comment: Looks like a namespace issue. I was able to fix it by adding `using ns::operator<<;' to `main()`.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6895993/10077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyValue` is an alias for `std::pair`. The namespace in which the alias template is defined is not considered as associated namespace for ADL. Only the class and enclosing namespace scope of the class `std::pair` itself will be considered.

Therefore the operator overload inside `ns` is not found.

It *is* found if you move `Foo_t` inside `ns`, because the class scope and enclosing namespace scope of type template arguments in the types of function arguments *are* considered for ADL.

If `Foo_t` is inside `ns`, then `ns` will be added to the list of associated scopes which will be searched, because it is a type template argument of `foo_kv`'s class type. If `Foo_t` is declared in the global namespace scope, then only the global namespace scope is added (which is already searched by unqualified lookup anyway).

As for how to fix it: If you want the operator overload to be found no matter what template arguments are used, then you can make `KeyValue` a distinct type:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
struct KeyValue : std::pair<KEY, VALUE> {
    using std::pair<KEY, VALUE>::pair;
};
```

or you can move the operator overload into the global namespace.